# Laravel - Returning 405 GET Method Not Allowed on the server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I want to change status enable and disable with ajax request
it works on localhost but when I want to use it on the server it gives me this error
:

> 405 GET Method Not Allowed

this is my ajax :

```php
<script>
    $(".change").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "vouchers/change-status/"+id,
                type: 'put',
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    "id": id,
                    "_method": 'put',
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                }

            });

    });

</script>
```

here is contorller

```php
public function changeStatus(Request $request){
        $voucher = Voucher::find($request->id);
        if($voucher->status == 0)
            $voucher->status = 1;
        else
            $voucher->status = 0;
        $voucher->save();
}
```

and web

```php
Route::put('vouchers/change-status/{id}', 'VoucherController@changeStatus')->name('change.status.voucher');
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201624/discussion-on-question-by-hassan-khosro-laravel-returning-405-get-method-not-a).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url: "vouchers/change-status/"+id,
                type: POST,
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    "id": id,
                    "_method": 'PUT',
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                }

            }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dataType` attribute is only used when you're getting data from the server. You should be setting `contentType` to `application/json` when sending data to the server.

```js
$(".change").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "vouchers/change-status/"+id
        headers: {"X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT"},
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "_method": 'put',
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        }
    });
});
```